# 14.04: password not accepted after computer wakes up from sleep

Tags: unity, suspend, lock-screen

If i press Ctrl+alt+L to lock the screen, I can get back in by typing my password.

If I put the computer to sleep, wake it back up again, I cannot log in anymore because it says the password is invalid.

The password is valid, because when I press Ctrl+F1 to go to tty1 I can log in using my username and this exact password.
Ctrl-F7 back to unity, the same password is invalid, and I have to restart in order to log back in. Very annoying.

The problem is reproducible every time the computer goes to sleep. I have an Intel HD4000 graphic and I'm using opensource drivers. The system is 14.04 with the latest updates through the official channel.

Comment: try toggling caps lock and make sure it is off.

Comment: already tried that

Comment: Just Switch account and enter your password there. Then you can login

Comment: That's only a work-around. Is this bug in launchpad already or should I file it?

Comment: @Philipp, did you file a bug report in Launchpad? I don't want to create a duplicate.

Comment: This is also the case in 16.04

Answer (score 4):

Same problem.

I found that it goes away if you try to switch account: then the password is accepted.

Do you have more than one language installed?

I was wondering about that because sometimes after loggin out I also get the wrong language activated.

Comment: Welcome to the community.
Please, write only your Solution to the question as an answer; to make comments or go deep in the question ("Do you have more than one language installed?") use the comment link under the question; to make more questions create a new topic. Next time a reviewer may edit your answer if you don't do so. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever is still seeing this problem...
Adding the default keyboard layout for X11 solved the problem for me. Create the folloing file:

/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-keyboard.conf

With the correct keyboard layout (fr for me):

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "keyboard"
    MatchIsKeyboard "yes"
    Option "XkbLayout" "fr"
    Option "XkbVariant" "latin9"
EndSection
```