# Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop lost open app windows after waking up from the sleep mode

Tags: 14.04, launcher, google-chrome, suspend

I am new to Ubuntu Desktop but have used Windows and Mac for a long time. I also have good experience with Linux. I need some help on how to recover the lost app windows.

I have been quite impressed by Ubuntu Desktop so far until I run into this problem. I use Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop on a Toshiba laptop with an external monitor. I use Chrome browser and Terminal apps frequently to develop software. I need to keep these app windows open for several days. I put the laptop into sleep mode between work sessions.

I often find some open windows are lost after waking up the laptop from the sleep mode. For example, I use Chrome browser to research topics. After waking up the laptop, I cannot find the Chrome window anymore. I can open a new Chrome window from the Chrome icon on the launcher. After that, if I click the Chrome icon on the launcher again, I can see both Chrome windows. But I cannot choose the old one.

This happens to both Chrome and Terminal apps so far. Can someone give me pointers on what I might have done wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Please help. Is this problem unique to me?

Comment: I am facing the same problem on lenovo T450, Ubuntu-16  and with terminal windows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong that may cause this problem.

Ubuntu 14.04 uses the relatively new [Unity user interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface)) that a still has a few rough edges, as well as a more recent Linux kernel (3.13+).

Many of us are having a series of issues:

[14.04: password not accepted after computer wakes up from sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459720/14-04-password-not-accepted-after-computer-wakes-up-from-sleep)
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1299778
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1280300

From time to time Chrome has also crashed for me (you should see an [Apport](https://launchpad.net/apport) dialog showing up when that happens), especially after waking up the computer.

Try searching [Ubuntu bugs in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/) and if nothing like your problem shows up for 14.04, consider filing a new bug report. This is your best shot at getting the issue fixed.